# How to edit textbox that will change values in MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Alright, so I have a search field where you can search a doctors name, when you click search button it will goto another page where it will have disabled textboxes with the values of what's in the database. I want to create an edit button so when you click it, it will reenable the textboxes to where you can edit the values and once you have clicked "save" it will change the values in the database?

This is what I have on my results page:

```
<?php
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){
//echo '<form>';

echo '<br /><img style="margin-left:10px;width:300px;height:300px;" src="'.$row['PhotoID'].'"</img>';
//echo '<p style="margin-top:50px;">Click to enlarge</p>';
echo '<b><p style="margin-left:400px;margin-top:-270px;">UID:</p> <input type="text" style="margin-left:460px;margin-top:-45px;width:400px;" class="form-control" disabled="true" value="' .$row['ID'].'">';
echo '<b><br /> <p style="margin-left:343px;">First Name:</p> <input type="text" disabled="true" style="margin-left:460px;margin-top:-45px;width:400px;" class="form-control" value="' .$row['FirstName']. '">';
echo '<b><br /> <p style="margin-left:350px;">Username:</p> <input type="text" disabled="true" style="margin-left:460px;margin-top:-45px;width:400px;" class="form-control" value="'.$row['LastName'].'">';
echo '<b><br /> <p style="margin-left:365px;">Verified:</p> <input type="text" disabled="true" style="margin-left:460px;margin-top:-45px;width:400px;" class="form-control" value="'.$row['Verified'].'">';
echo '<strong><br /><br /> <p style="margin-left:350px;">Notes:</p> <textarea class="form-control" disabled style="width: 800px;height:300px;margin-left:350px;" name="notes">'.$row['Notes'].'</textarea>';
    } else {
        echo '<center><h1 style="margin-top:50px;">No doctor by that name was found!</h1>';
    }
}
?>

<h5 style="margin-left:120px;margin-top:-300px;">Actions:</h5>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="margin-left:60px;width:100px;">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" style="width:100px;">Delete</button>
```

My question is what do I do after I click the edit button?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking to edit data in database? if so then make an attribute tag with a link  like below

```
<a href="edit.php?id=123">Edit</a>
<a href="editdata.php?action=edit&id=123">Edit</a>
```

here id is the specific row id of a table inside the database. So you are sending an id to **edit.php** page. After that, check inside **edit.php** like below

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id']; //sanitize as your own wish
}
```

After that, make a query a get data from the database according to id like below.

```
$con = new mysqli('host','user','pass','database');
if($con){
 $stmt = $con->query("select * from table where id='$id'");
 if($stmt){
   $result = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
  }
}
```

and finally, use this result value in the form field like below

```
<form action='something.php'>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['name']; ?>">
    <input type='submit' value="Update">

</form>
```

Go ahead, in this way. Hope that, you will get solution of your problem. If you failed. Just knock at **arif98741**

Comment: You are opening the OP to SQL injections.